# Is it possible to not be dependent on the array index in Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise

This is a code form my project:

```
    const [
        page,
        hierarchies,
        courses,
    ] = await Promise.all([
        usePage('home'),
        useHierarchies('course'),
        useCoursesByConfigKeys(['firstCourses', 'secondCourses'])
    ])
```

As you can see, I'm wrapping three `async` methods inside a `Promise.all` call.

And it works great. I then destructure the output array into constants that I can use later.

However, there is a big problem here. If I change the index of the inputs, without changing the index of the outputs (by mistake), then the destructuring won't happen correctly.

In other words, this code still compiles, but would give me run-time errors:

```
    const [
        page,
        hierarchies,
        courses,
    ] = await Promise.all([
        useHierarchies('course'),
        useCoursesByConfigKeys(['firstCourses', 'secondCourses'])
        usePage('home'),
    ])
```

Just tell me if it's possible to somehow use object destructuring instead of array destructuring for this purpose. Something like this:

```
    const {
        page,
        hierarchies,
        courses,
    } = await Promise.all({
        hierarchies: useHierarchies('course'),
        courses: useCoursesByConfigKeys(['firstCourses', 'secondCourses'])
        page: usePage('home'),
    })
```

Comment: No, `Promise.all` takes an array. But you could write a wrapper to use objects instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function which converts an object to an array of its values, passes that array through `Promise.all`, then then maps the original keys onto the matching resolved promises.

```js
/**
 * Creates a Promise that is resolved with an record of results when all of the provided Promises resolve, or rejected when any Promise is rejected.
 * @template {Record<string, Promise<any>>} R
 * @param {R} obj A record of Promises
 * @returns {Promise<{ [K in keyof R]: Awaited<R[K]>; }>} A record of results.
 */
const namedPromiseAll = async (obj) => {
  const entryPromises = Object.entries(obj).map(
    async ([key, promise]) => [key, await promise]
  );
  return Object.fromEntries(await Promise.all(entryPromises));
}

void async function () {

  const {
    foo /* : number */, bar /* : string */, baz /* : boolean */
  } = await namedPromiseAll({
    foo: Promise.resolve(12345),
    bar: Promise.resolve('bar'),
    baz: Promise.resolve(true),
  })
  console.log({ foo, bar, baz })

}()
```

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev It worked fine, I just didn't like it rely on `Object.keys` and `Object.values` using the same order. If Quentin doesn't like the edit, he can roll it back. And no, I did not copy your solution, your answer had not even shown up until I saved the edit.

Comment: @Bergi — I was kicking myself when I saw your implementation. I'd been trying to figure out how to get it to work with a simple `entries`.

Comment: This is lovely! Very nice code!

Comment: I've added JSDoc for type support